# What is the minimum TLS version for support of Ed25519 Keys?

Tags: tls, ecc

I'm setting up a client TLS CA for authenticating requests over the internet to an AWS API Gateway endpoint. It supports TLS 1.2 but not TLS 1.3, at least from what I can tell.

Is there a minimum version of TLS 1.2 for support of Ed25519 certificates?